# Class IndeX cpp?

Tags: c++

lets say my code looks like this:

```
[...]
class klasse{
public: 
int Var1;
int Var2;
};

klasse Klasse1;
klasse Klasse2;
klasse Klasse3;



Klasse1.Var1=1;
Klasse2.Var1=1;
Klasse3.Var1=1;
//now watch 
if(Klasse1.Var1==1)
{
Klasse1.Var2=1;
}
if(Klasse2.Var1==1)
{
Klasse2.Var2=1;
}
if(Klasse2.Var1==1)
{
Klasse2.Var2=1;
}
```

U understand the Problem?
i want to have a For-loop for the VaribleNames
Like this:

```
[...]
class klasse{
public: 
int Var1;
int Var2;
};


klasse Klasse1;
klasse Klasse2;
klasse Klasse3;



Klasse1.Var1=1;
Klasse2.Var1=1;
Klasse3.Var1=1;

for(int i=0; i<3; i++)
{
if(Klasse[i].Var1==1)
{
Klasse[i].Var2=1;
}
}
```

i tryed to do it with a vector but it does not work correcly, or how it shoud work, maybe im just to incompetent for that

Comment: ⟼Remember, it's always important, *especially* when learning and asking questions on Stack Overflow, to keep your code as organized as possible. [Consistent indentation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indentation_style) helps communicate structure and, importantly, intent, which helps us navigate quickly to the root of the problem without spending a lot of time trying to decode what's going on.

Comment: If you want to use a for loop then just create an array of `klasse` objects? Not sure I understand the problem

Comment: You've already identified the solution: `std::vector`. What happened when you tried that?

Comment: I didnt use it the right way, there was a Erorr in int the vector

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your idea of using a `vector` is a good one.

```cpp
int main(void) {
    std::vector<klasse> klasses(3);

    for (int i=0; i<3; i++)
        klasses[i].var1 = 1;

    for (int i=0; i<3; i++)
        if (klasses[i].var1 == 1)
            klasses[i].var2 = 1;
}
```

Alternative, you could use range-based for loops:

```cpp
    for (auto &k : klasses)
       if (k.var1 == 1)
           k.var2 = 1;
```